# Play Framework: Stream file content to S3

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, playframework

I am trying to stream file content to S3 using Play's `EssentialAction` in the following way:

```
  def upload(fileName: String) = EssentialAction { request =>
    val (iteratee, enumerator) = Concurrent.joined[Array[Byte]]
    blobStore.streamToStore(fileName, enumerator) //consumes the enumerator, streams to S3 and returns Future[Unit]
    iteratee.map { _ =>
      Logger.debug(s"Successfully uploaded file=$fileName")
      Created(Json.obj("id" -> fileName))
    }
  }
```

The above works if `blobStore.streamToStore` streams successfully but if there is any error while streaming, the request is never completed, doing a `recover` on `iteratee` does not help as well. Can someone throw some light as how to handle errors in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to finish consuming the enumerator on error:

```
blobStore.streamToStore(fileName, enumerator).recover {
  case throwable =>
    /* consume the enumerator for request to complete */
    enumerator |>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().map(_ => throw throwable)
}
iteratee.map { _ =>
  Logger.debug(s"Successfully uploaded file=$fileName")
  Created(Json.obj("id" -> fileName))
}.recover {
  case NonFatal(throwable) => 
     InternalServerError(Results.EmptyContent())
}
```